# How to check if condition already exists in shopping cart price rule?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to find out if the condition that I am going to set in the price rule already exists or not.
I tried to check if it is valid or not but couldn't find the correct function I think.

```
        if($voucherRule->getConditions()->validate($realProduct)){
            echo "<br> Already exists<br>";
            $foundamatch = true;
        }

        if(!$foundamatch){
             $item_found = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
        ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
        ->setValue(1) // 1 == FOUND
        ->setAggregator('any'); // match ANY conditions
             $skuCondition = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
        ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
        ->setAttribute('sku')
        ->setOperator('==')
        ->setValue($realProduct->getSku());
            $voucherRule->getConditions()->addCondition($item_found);
            $item_found->addCondition($skuCondition);
        }
        $voucherRule->save();
```

Did not work, it always creates the same conditions over and over again when ever I run the script.

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way t odo so. See the code below (It works like a charm!):

```
    try{
        $foundamatch = false;
        $unserializedConditions = unserialize($voucherRule->getData('conditions_serialized'));

        foreach($unserializedConditions['conditions'] as $conditions){
            foreach($conditions['conditions'] as $subcond){
                if($subcond['value'] == $sku)
                {
                    echo "<br>Product SKU condition already Exists!<br>";
                    $foundamatch = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!$foundamatch){
            $voucherRule->getConditions()->addCondition($item_found);
            $item_found->addCondition($skuCondition);
        }
        $voucherRule->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own anser so that the question does not count as unanswered anymore